# Error "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request"

Tags: c#, sockets, exception

My application is working as a client application for a bank server. The application is sending a request and getting a response from the bank. This application is normally working fine, but sometimes

> The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or
> an application request

error with error code as 995 (0x3E3) comes through.

```
public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    BLCommonFunctions.WriteLogger(
        0,
        "In: OnDataReceived",
        ref swReceivedLogWriter, 
        strLogPath, 
        0);
    try
    {
        SocketPacket theSockId = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;

        int iRx = theSockId.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn); // Here the error is coming
        string strHEX = BLCommonFunctions.ByteArrToHex(theSockId.dataBuffer);
    }
}
```

Once this error starts to come for all transactions after that same error begin to appear, so how can I sort out this problem?

If possible then with some sample code.

Comment: There are few Windows errors that are as descriptive and reliable as that one.  We can't help you find the thread that is terminating too early.  Add some tracing to your code if you can't find it.

Comment: I had this exception raised while using IPython, when simply running code defining a function, and the code had nothing to do with client-server communication. For those with similar issues, [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355904/why-do-i-get-an-unhandled-exception-in-event-loop-error-on-ipython).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

995 is an error reported by the [IO Completion Port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The error comes since you try to continue read from the socket when it has most likely been closed.

Receiving 0 bytes from `EndRecieve` means that the socket has been closed, as does most exceptions that `EndRecieve` will  throw.

You need to start dealing with those situations.

***Never ever ignore exceptions. They are thrown for a reason.***

There is nothing that says that the server does anything wrong. A connection can be lost for a lot of reasons, such as an idle connection being closed by a switch/router/firewall, shaky network, bad cables, etc.

I'm saying that you *must* handle disconnections. The proper way of doing so is to dispose the socket and try to connect a new one at certain intervals.

As for the receive callback a more proper way of handling it is something like this (semi pseudo code):

```
public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    BLCommonFunctions.WriteLogger(
        0,
        "In: OnDataReceived",
        ref swReceivedLogWriter,
        strLogPath,
        0);
    try
    {
        SocketPacket client = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;

        int bytesReceived = client.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn); // Here the error is coming
        if (bytesReceived == 0)
        {
          HandleDisconnect(client);
          return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
       HandleDisconnect(client);
    }

    try
    {
        string strHEX = BLCommonFunctions.ByteArrToHex(theSockId.dataBuffer);

        // Do your handling here
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        // Your logic threw an exception. handle it accordinhly
    }

    try
    {
       client.thisSocket.BeginRecieve(.. all parameters ..);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
       HandleDisconnect(client);
    }
}
```

The reason to why I'm using three catch blocks is simply because the logic for the middle one is different from the other two. Exceptions from BeginReceive/EndReceive usually indicates socket disconnection while exceptions from your logic should not stop the socket receiving.

Comment: Dear jgauffin, Thanks for your response, but issue is that only client application is from our company and server is from some bank, so if socket closed from their side then how to express them that this problem is from their side also how can we handle this without exception i.e. as it throws exception in endreceive can we write any command which will tell us that receiving data is 0

Comment: @funsukvangdu: Do you have any more questions?

Comment: More info on error 995: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14480048/67824

Answer (score 24):

In my case, the request was getting timed out. So all you need to do is to increase the time out while creating the HttpClient.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```

Comment: There's no mention of a HttpClient in the question?

Comment: I have client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20); and still have this issue.

Comment: You  might have to move the HttpClient object instantiation outside the current scope block. Maybe something try to access the object after it has been disposed at the end of the scope.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with [RS-232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) communication. The reason is that your program executes much faster than the [COM port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_%28hardware_interface%29) (or slow serial communication).

To fix it, I had to check if the `IAsyncResult.IsCompleted==true`. If not completed, then `IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()`

Like this:

```
Stream s = this.GetStream();
IAsyncResult ar = s.BeginWrite(data, 0, data.Length, SendAsync, state);
if (!ar.IsCompleted)
    ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

Most of the time, `ar.IsCompleted` will be `true`.

Comment: If the `EndWrite` is directly below that code, you should use `Write` instead of your code. There is no performance improvement of using Begin/WaitOne/End, on the contrary, the code will be slower and waste allocations.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the issue was caused by the fact that starting from .NET 5 or 6, you must either call async methods for an async stream, or sync methods for a sync stream.

So that if I called `FlushAsync`, I must have get context using `GetContextAsync`.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. I think that it was caused by the socket getting opened and no data arriving within a short time after the open. I was reading from a serial-to-Ethernet box called a Devicemaster.

I changed the Devicemaster port setting from "connect always" to "connect on data" and the problem disappeared.

I have great respect for Hans Passant, but I do not agree that this is an error code that you can easily solve by scrutinizing code.

Answer (score 2):

When it happens, I **Disable** the COM port into the **Device Manager** and **Enable** it again.

It stops the communications with another program or thread and become free for you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error while using [Entity Framework Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework#History) (EF) with Azure SQL Server running in Debug mode in Visual Studio.

I figured out that it is an exception, but not a problem.  EF is written to handle this exception gracefully and complete the work.  I had Visual Studio set to break on all exceptions, so it did.  Once I unchecked the check box in Visual Studio to not break on this exception, my C# code, calling EF, using Azure SQL Server worked every time.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh yes. Error 995 == 0x3E3. I've just stumbled across this while working with serial communications, and obtaining data with a parity error. There's an attribute in the [DCB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-dcb) struct that is related to this behavior:

DCB::fAbortOnError == [TRUE | FALSE]

When configured as TRUE, and a parity error occurs in the RX data,

> the driver terminates all read and write operations with an error status. The driver will not accept any further communications operations until the application has acknowledged the error by calling the [ClearCommError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-clearcommerror) function.

That's a quote from the Microsoft documentation on the [DCB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-dcb).
The ABORT thing can actually happen on other errors as well, apart from parity... none of which I have experienced so far.