# CommEvent overlapped in Qt

Tags: qt, qextserialport

I'm using Qextserialport in QT, but I keep getting a waring:

```
CommEvent overlapped write error: 995
```

What does this warning mean? And more important, how do I solve it?

Comment: From [the source](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/source/browse/src/qextserialport_win.cpp), it seems that this warning is given only in Windows, when `GetOverlappedResult()` fails and `GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE`

Comment: @Frank: considered switching to QtSerialPort?

Answer (score 1):

From [the source](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/source/browse/src/qextserialport_win.cpp) it seems 995 is what `GetLastError()` returned. 995 stands for `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED` - *The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.*

This is from `winerror.h`:

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED
//
// MessageText:
//
// The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
//
#define ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED          995L
```