# Why do I get an 'Unhandled exception in event loop' error on ipython

Tags: python

I started using ipython recently. Now I often get this message upon doing any action, even simple ones like defining variables:

```
>>> num = 1

Unhandled exception in event loop:
File "c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 768, in _loop_self_reading
    f.result()  # may raise
File "c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 808, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)   
File "c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 457, in finish_recv
    raise ConnectionResetError(*exc.args)

Exception [WinError 995] The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
Press ENTER to continue...
```

This message sometimes shows up, sometimes not, for the same command. Have no idea what I did wrong. The normal interpreter doesn't have this problem. Using 3.8 and installed ipython 7.10.2 through the cmd.
Thanks.

Comment: provide code example please

Comment: I'm just trying to type in something like
xyz = "hello"
and getting the above message

Comment: @ziggy welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: beatrice, I actually think this is all. No code... @ziggy, is this all? Do you just start your live interpreter, type in a variable, like `num=1`, and the error occurs? No code is running? If so, I would assume something has gone wrong with the installation.

Comment: @magnus exactly. It's not a code problem. I just want to use ipython on a new computer and have no idea what went wrong. I tried reinstalling several times but it didn't help.

Comment: @ziggy, from the content of the error message, I assume you're on Windows; which version: XP, 7, 8, 10 ..? How did you install IPython, and is it Python 2 or 3? Please add these details to your post to avoid prolonged discussion here in the comments' section :)

Answer (score 31):

I managed to solve the problem. There is some incompatibility between the ipython v7.10.2 and prompt toolkit v3.x. However, everything works fine when downgrading to prompt toolkit v2.x:

```
python -m pip install -U prompt-toolkit~=2.0
```

I was advised to do so by the ipython staff at github (so credit to them).

Comment: Had the same problem recently after upgrading `ipython` (and all its dependencies). Previously, it just randomly prompted me to `Press Enter to Continue` for stuff that shouldn't have needed it (`In [1]: 1 + 2` would do it roughly a third of the time); after the upgrade, it started dumping the same traceback you described too. Downgrading `prompt_toolkit` seems to have solved both problems. Guessing the problem was the same in both cases, but different versions of `ipython` and its various dependencies changed whether it died loudly (w/traceback) or quietly (`Press Enter` prompt only). Thanks!

Comment: This fix worked for me .  https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12049#issuecomment-586544339  --    on `win10`, `ipython 7.13.0`, `prompt-toolkit 3.0.5`, `python 3.8.2 win32`, using  `bash` from git-bash inside `windows terminal` (latest)