# Django Winerror 995?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm taking the Django tutorials and using Pycharm.
All seems good except on occasion I'll get:

```
>>> from polls.models import Choice, Question  # Import the model classes we just wrote.

# No questions are in the system yet.
>>> Question.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>

# Create a new Question.
# Support for time zones is enabled in the default settings file, so
# Django expects a datetime with tzinfo for pub_date. Use timezone.now()
# instead of datetime.datetime.now() and it will do the right thing.
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> q = Question(question_text="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())

# Save the object into the database. You have to call save() explicitly.
>>> q.save()

# Now it has an ID.
>>> q.id
1

# Access model field values via Python attributes.
>>> q.question_text
"What's new?"

print(q)
2What's new?
Unhandled exception in event loop:
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 768, in _loop_self_reading
    f.result()  # may raise
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 808, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 457, in finish_recv
    raise ConnectionResetError(*exc.args)

Exception [WinError 995] The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
Press ENTER to continue...
print(q)
2What's new?
```

I'm using Pycharm 2019.3.3 and Python 3.8 on Win10.
To resolve I run the same command again and there's no error.

Comment: What's `q` in your code? Also is there a particular `view` you hit that causes this error to occur? Some more code is required.

Comment: q is the question model from the DJango tutorial.

Comment: If this error comes randomly, I am afraid I can't help you. I Linux, Vim guy, don't know windows. Maybe if this was a little consistent due to some View, that can help in further investigation.

Comment: Maybe it's your DB connection, it's probably timing out. Try something other than sqlite if this is what you're using.

Comment: I'm using Postgresql

Comment: Okay, I searched around a bit and this may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355904/why-do-i-get-an-unhandled-exception-in-event-loop-error-on-ipython Here's the github issue for this as well https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12049